# What species is this rabbit-like animal?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, mammals

This image was included in something I was browsing through.
It reminds me of my lion head rabbit, but the head shape doesn't match.

Is this some kind of Siberian wild rabbit?

[image: Its sooooo fluuuuuufy!!!]

Comment: Google image search yielded a lot of references to ***wise bunny***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does indeed seem to be a **viscacha**, which are actually found in South America (not Siberia). Their morphological similarity to rabbits is simply a case of [convergent evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_evolution), as these animals are in the rodent order ([Rodentia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodent)) [whearas rabbits are order [Lagomorpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagomorpha)].

Viscacha consist of two genera ([*Lagidium*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagidium) and [*Lagostomus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagostomus)). However, your image much more closely resembles one of the 3 *Lagidium* species in a morphological sense, and your mountainous background also supports *Lagidium* as these are considered "mountain viscacha."

Which mountain viscacha you have pictured is difficult to say (and I'm certainly no expert). If we knew location of the original image, we'd be abl to narrow down easier. From a morphological sense, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscacha) claims that the two most common mountainous species can be differentiated because the northern viscacha (*Lagidium peruanum*) is grey/brown on its back while the southern viscacha (*Lagidium viscacia*) has redder-colored fur.

- However, the individual Wikipedia pages for each species suggest that the northern species has a "cream or pale grey" belly while the southern species has "yellowish-grey upperparts [and] paler underparts."
- Given this [somewhat unclear] information, I'm still not certain on species. If I had to guess between these two I'd guess your image shows a **northern viscacha ([*Lagidium peruanum*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Northern_viscacha))**.

[image]

<sup>Source: [BBC Planet Earth II](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/p04fgpzv/p04fgpvn)</sup>

Comment: hmm.. interest... who am i kidding.. _they're soooo cuuuuuute!_

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to @Satwik's tip about google image search, I was able to figure out that the animal in question is a [Viscacha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscacha). Though the source answer is thanks to [reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/m10e0/wise_bunny_meditates/), so take that as you will.

> Viscachas or vizcachas are rodents of two genera (Lagidium and Lagostomus) in the family Chinchillidae. They are closely related to chinchillas, and look similar to rabbits, apart from their longer tails